# Nginx authentication using JWT and an external authentication server in a multi-tenant system

Tags: nginx

I am building a multi-tenant system fronted by Nginx.

I want all requests hitting Nginx to first be 'filtered' on whether they have a valid JWT. If not, there should be a 'call out' to an external authentication server which will do SAML/SSO and return a JWT or 'false'. If false, then a 401 is returned.

If there is a valid JWT, it needs to be interpreted and the tenant name extracted. Then, depending on the request path, the url/POST body will need to be modified to include the correct tenant (we are hitting an Elasticsearch and need to make sure that a tenant is only allowed to query their own indexes)

The Authentication server will be built in php, so what we need is just the 'filter' part and a valid way of calling the Auth server. Is there any off-the-shelf nginx module which will solve this requirement? Or is Lua my best bet here? I'm a relatively novice Nginx-er.

Answer (score 2):

There is much better and simpler JWT based authentication module for nginx.
Highly configurable.
https://github.com/tarachandverma/nginx-openidc

You can configure multiple relying parties.
https://github.com/tarachandverma/nginx-openidc/blob/master/test-conf/oidc-config.xml#L12

```
<!-- relying parties configuration -->
 <relyingParties default="282412598309-545pvmsh9r23f4k1o7267744s59sod6v.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <relyingParty clientID="282412598309-545pvmsh9r23f4k1o7267744s59sod6v.apps.googleusercontent.com" clientSecret="xxxxx" domain=".com" validateNonce="true">
        <description>nginx oidc demo</description>
        <redirectUri>http://ngx-oidc-demo.com/oauth2/callback</redirectUri>
    </relyingParty>
 </relyingParties>
```

Comment: Please do not post link only answers, as the link may break. Take the relevant content from the link and post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Use https://github.com/auth0/nginx-jwt, for me it was easier to install Openresty, since I didn't have that much time to install manually lua module on nginx, and all it's dependencies.

At https://github.com/auth0/nginx-jwt/blob/master/nginx-jwt.lua at the line 114 the library adds the sub to the header which should be an Id, you may change this if you need anything alse.

`ngx.header["X-Auth-UserId"] = jwt_obj.payload.sub`